# Ranking algorithm with win-lose records

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ranking

I am looking for an algorithmic approach to sort elements based on its win-lose records of each combiniation.

Please take a look at the sample data

```
('a', 'b') -> (W, L)
('a', 'c') -> (L, W)
('a', 'd') -> (L, W)
('a', 'e') -> (W, L)
('b', 'c') -> (L, W)
('b', 'd') -> (L, W)
('b', 'e') -> (W, L)
('c', 'd') -> (W, L)
('c', 'e') -> (W, L)
('d', 'e') -> (W, L)
```

The winner is placed right side of the array

ex)

- `c` win over all the other elements
- `d` win over all the other elements except c
  ...

Desired result ordered from Lost -> Win

```
[e, b, a, d, c]
```

Is there a keyword, or approach I can chase on to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include why is the order so in the desired result for the given sample data.

Comment: @SomeDude I have added the reason for the desired result for the given sample data. Thank you.

Comment: Based on your example, you're sorting by win / loss percentage ascending.  Calculate the win / loss percentage for each player, then sort.

Comment: Basically, you are asking "how do I decide the ranking order at the end of a tournament"? There are lots of ways that tournaments can be run which can produce different outcomes.

Comment: You can run through each item in the dictionary ( assuming your data is dict ) and then for each player increment a counter if 'W' is marked for that and decrement it when its 'L' , finally you will have for each player number of wins ( could be negative ). Then just sort based on number of wins.

Comment: What if several players have the same win/loss percentage?

Comment: Remember to give feedback on answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about by assigning each token, `w`, `l`, (and you could do draw `d`) a value, such as `w=3, l=1, d=2`.

Then you would map those values to each player's result and you'd sort it accordingly.

So from your example of:

```
('a', 'b') -> (W, L)
('a', 'c') -> (L, W)
('a', 'd') -> (L, W)
('a', 'e') -> (W, L)
('b', 'c') -> (L, W)
('b', 'd') -> (L, W)
('b', 'e') -> (W, L)
('c', 'd') -> (W, L)
('c', 'e') -> (W, L)
('d', 'e') -> (W, L)
```

gets mapped to something like this:

```
('a', 'b') -> (2, 1)
('a', 'c') -> (1, 2)
('a', 'd') -> (1, 2)
('a', 'e') -> (2, 1)
('b', 'c') -> (1, 2)
('b', 'd') -> (1, 2)
('b', 'e') -> (2, 1)
('c', 'd') -> (2, 1)
('c', 'e') -> (2, 1)
('d', 'e') -> (2, 1)
```

Sum up the values by their key:

```
a: 6
b: 4
c: 8
d: 7
e: 4
```

and sort the values starting with lowest:

```
b: 4
e: 4
a: 6
d: 7
c: 8
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not a native English speaker, please forgive me if there is any grammatical error.

Record the number of wins and losses for each letter, the letter that has not been lost is the largest letter, and the letter that has not been won is the smallest letter.

This problem can be transformed into the longest path algorithm. You can think of each comparison as a path of length 1, so that the longest path from the smallest letter to the largest letter represents the result.

Answer (score -1):

This assumes that the ordering is based on number of wins per item.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630173/ranking-algorithm-with-win-lose-records

Created on Fri May 21 19:00:33 2021

@author: Paddy3118
"""

data = {('a', 'b'): ('W', 'L'),
('a', 'c'): ('L', 'W'),
('a', 'd'): ('L', 'W'),
('a', 'e'): ('W', 'L'),
('b', 'c'): ('L', 'W'),
('b', 'd'): ('L', 'W'),
('b', 'e'): ('W', 'L'),
('c', 'd'): ('W', 'L'),
('c', 'e'): ('W', 'L'),
('d', 'e'): ('W', 'L'),
}

all_items = set()
for (i1, i2) in data.keys():
    all_items |= {i1, i2}       # Finally = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}

win_counts = {item: 0 for item in all_items}
for (i1, i2), (r1, r2) in data.items():
    if r1 == 'W':
        win_counts[i1] += 1
    else:
        win_counts[i2] += 1

# win_counts = {'a': 2, 'd': 3, 'b': 1, 'e': 0, 'c': 4}

answer = sorted(all_items, key=lambda i: win_counts[i])
print(answer)  # ['e', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'c']
```